# C: mysql_store_result() and mysql_fetch_row() in different functions

Tags: mysql, c

I have an issue using the functions mysql_store_result() and mysql_fetch_row() in different functions.

If I'm doing it like this everything works fine:

```
int main() {
  MYSQL *connection;
  MYSQL_RES *result;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  //Connect to database

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY column1 ASC");
  result = mysql_use_result(connection);
  row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
  puts(row[0]);

  //Free results & close connection
}
```

But when I'm trying to do it in two different functions I always get an error on mysql_fetch_row(result) saying: No source available for "mysql_fetch_row() at 0xb781454d".

I tried these two ways (didn't free the results or close the connection in database()):

```
int main() {
  MYSQL_RES *result;
  MYSQL_ROW row;

  database(result);
  row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
  puts(row[0]);

  //free results
}

void database(MYSQL_RES *result) {
  MYSQL *connection;
  //Connect to database

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY column1 ASC");
  result = mysql_use_result(connection);
}
```

and

```
int main() {
  MYSQL *connection;
  MYSQL_RES *result;
  MYSQL_ROW row;

  database(connection);
  result = mysql_use_result(connection);
  row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
  puts(row[0]);

  //close connection & free results
}

void database(MYSQL *connection) {
  //Connect to database

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY column1 ASC");
}
```

So my questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is it possible to have the select and the output in two different functions without copying all results in a different structure in the RAM?
3. I'm trying to implement this in procedural programming without Object Orientation. What would be best practise?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of your attempts fails because `database` is passed a pointer to a `MYSQL_RES` by value.  This means that it operates on a copy of the caller's variable and doesn't affect the state of the caller's variable.  If you want to modify the caller's variable, you need to pass a pointer to it i.e. a `MYSQL_RES**`

```
int main() {
    ....
    database(&result);
    ....
}

void database(MYSQL_RES **result) {
  MYSQL *connection;
  //Connect to database

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY column1 ASC");
  *result = mysql_use_result(connection);
}
```

Alternatively, it'd be easier in this case if you changed `database` to return a `MYSQL_RES*`

```
int main() {
    ....
    result = database();
    ....
}

MYSQL_RES* database() {
  MYSQL *connection;
  //Connect to database

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY column1 ASC");
  return mysql_use_result(connection);
}
```

The second of your refactored options fails for similar reasons but with `connection` being the problem variable.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Thought MYSQL_RES *result would already be a pointer.

Comment: @user2493165 It is already a pointer.  Which was being passed by value into another function.  Passing by value means passing a copy of the variable.  When you want to change the value of a pointer variable in another function, you need to pass a pointer to it (so a pointer to a pointer)